# Нужна помощь Python со стимом

Tags: python, steam

Нужно чтобы игра скачивалась в стиме по айди через SteamCmd но возникает ошибка

```
import subprocess
def download_game_from_steam(app_id):
    steamcmd_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamcmd.exe"
    app_install_dir = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common"   
    command = f'"{steamcmd_path}" +force_install_dir "{app_install_dir}" +login anonymous +app_update {app_id} validate +quit'
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
app_id = "730"
download_game_from_steam(app_id)
```

Ошибка

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: [документация](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Downloading_SteamCMD:~:text=Known%20Issues-,ERROR!%20Failed%20to%20install%20app%20%22xxxxxx%22%20(No%20subscription),-If%20you%20get) к ошибке